# How do I know what to put in my interfaces?

Tags: c#, oop, interface, polymorphism

I've come across this recurring problem when trying to design the logic for my programs. Let's say I have a IDriveable interface.

```
interface IDriveable
{
  public void Drive();
}
```

Then a car class that implements this (c#) syntax:

```
class Car : IDriveable
{
  public void Drive(){
  //Do the movement here.
  }

}
```

Here's where my problem occurs. If I am designing a game, the car doesn't drive itself, a player should drive the car, surely that makes sense?

```
class player
{
    public void Drive(IDriveable vehicle){

        vehicle.Drive();
     }
}
```

It feels like I am 'ping-ponging' the logic around which doesn't seem right.

Comment: when you have more then one IDriveable it will make sense. Driver/Player doesnt need to know details how it is going. it needs an interface to drive. yeah i think that makes sense.

Comment: every thing you wrote is correct because you can have also bike wich is also IDrivable, than if you give a player the IDrivable - the player dont care if it's a car or a bike he just Drive()

Comment: If the player has multiple objects that they can move, I'd suggest leaving `IDriveable` with the implementing objects, and then give the player an instance of that object which they could drive. I.e., if you have an instance of say `Car` named `FastCar`, then in player you'd do `FastCar.Drive()`.

Comment: In your example the player class has no purpose, so it is hard to say something about it. Make an example where the player class does something.

Comment: Interfaces are usually used when defining some characteristics/behavior horizontally, across multiple object hierachies. Depends on you, how much abstraction do you need and what hiearchies do you have in your design.

Comment: @user1743962 Being a new user I just wanted to give you a FYI, there is a [entire stack exchange site](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) devoted to just game development programming.

Comment: I would suggest reading [Services and Components](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Services-and-Components.ashx) from Castle Windsor. Okay, different language, and touching on IoC, but I think *one* critical view that relates: Services are defined by interfaces. Components use Services. I think this helps provide a *base-line* approach (although there are some valid patterns that run counter) for such decisions because a Car (really any IDrivable) is *used-by* a Driver. (IDrivable, being *used-by* would then contain things like "Accelerate", "Turn", etc.)

Answer (score 0):

A better way to structure your code might be something like this:

```
class Player // Start class names with a capital letter
{
    Car thisPlayersCar; // Initialize it  the constructor or somewhere appropriate

    public void someFunction() {
        thisPlayersCar.Drive();
    }
}
```

Basically, the purpose of an interface is that wherever you call `thisPlayersCar.Drive();` (or `Drive()` on any `IDriveable`), you're guaranteed that the object will have a `Drive()` function ready to go.